# Recycler view is not displaying in few mobiles. why?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view to display all the persons. But the problem is i am able to see it only on some device. It is not showing up in redmi , google pixel2..etc. What might be the reason?
I am attaching my xml code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".deliverymethods.searchps">
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:background="@drawable/searchback"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_action_dasearch"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp">
    </SearchView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:divider="@null"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my java class ....i have fetched my data and added to recyclerview

```
package com.bodaty.samyata.samyata09.deliverymethods;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bodaty.samyata.samyata09.R;
import com.bodaty.samyata.samyata09.adapters.CustomAdaptersearch;
import com.bodaty.samyata.samyata09.reviews_model.Model;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ListenerRegistration;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class searchps extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    CustomAdaptersearch mAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    String Firstname,lastname,image;
    String flag="0",productid;
    ListenerRegistration registration;
    SearchView searchView;
    String price="",time="";
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ArrayList<Model> ls_data;
    ArrayList<Model> loadList = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    int psCount = 0;
    int docCount = 0;
    int taskcount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchps);
        setTitle("Choose your Personal Shopper");

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        ls_data = new ArrayList<>();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        pd = new ProgressDialog(searchps.this);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        personalshoppers();
        searchView= findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search by Personal Shopper Name");
        int searchplate=searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate",null,null);
        View search=searchView.findViewById(searchplate);
        //searchView.setFocusable(false);
        if(search!=null){
            search.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        final Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        if(intent1.getStringExtra("Flag") != null) {
            flag = intent1.getStringExtra("Flag");
        }
        if(intent1.getStringExtra("productId") != null) {
            productid = intent1.getStringExtra("productId");
            Log.e("get in searchps",productid);
        }
        if(intent1.getStringExtra("price") != null) {
            price = intent1.getStringExtra("price");
        }

        if(intent1.getStringExtra("time") != null) {
            time = intent1.getStringExtra("time");
        }



        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ls_data.clear();
                    personalshoppers();

                } else {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(mAdapter!=null) {
                        searchps.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(searchps.this, "No matching data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Log.e("reached", "" + newText);

                if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ls_data.clear();
                    personalshoppers();

                    Log.e("no search", "empty");

                } else {
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(mAdapter!=null) {
                        searchps.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

//        CollectionReference query1 = db.collection("PersonalShoppers");
//        registration = query1.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
//            @Override
//            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
//                if (e != null) {
//                    Log.w("Q", "Listen failed.", e);
//                    return;
//                }
//                for (DocumentChange dc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
//                    switch (dc.getType()) {
//                        case ADDED:
//                            Log.d("searchps", "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
//                            break;
//                        case MODIFIED:
//                            String   isAttendance =  dc.getDocument().getData().get("Status").toString();
//                            Log.e("status update",isAttendance);
//                            Log.d("searchps", "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
////                            ls_data.clear();
////                            personalshoppers();
//                            break;
//                        case REMOVED:
//                            Log.d("searchps", "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
//                            break;
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//        });
    }


    private void personalshoppers() {

        db.collection("PersonalShoppers").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful() && !task.getResult().isEmpty()){

                    if(ls_data!=null) {
                        ls_data.clear();
                    }
                    if(loadList!=null){
                        loadList.clear();
                    }
                    count=0;
                    taskcount=task.getResult().size();
                    docCount=0;
                    for (final DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                        if (document.exists()) {
                            String id = document.getId();
                            if (!id.equals(mAuth.getUid())) {
                                docCount=docCount+1;

                                Object psid = document.getId();
                                final String status=document.getString("Status");
                                final Model m = new Model();
                                m.setUser_id(String.valueOf(psid));
                                m.setStatus(status);

                                if (id != null && !id.isEmpty() && status != null && !status.isEmpty()) {
                                    if(status.equals("online")){
                                        db.collection("UserProfile").document(id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                                                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                                                    Firstname = documentSnapshot.getString("FirstName");
                                                    lastname = documentSnapshot.getString("LastName");
                                                    image = documentSnapshot.getString("Image");
                                                    Object price = document.get("PriceRange");

                                                    if (Firstname != null && image != null && price != null && status != null) {
                                                        Log.e("first", Firstname);

                                                        m.setname(Firstname + " " + lastname);
                                                        m.setimage3(image);
                                                        m.setPrice(String.valueOf(price));
                                                        ls_data.add(m);
                                                        psCount = psCount + 1;
                                                        Log.e("pscount,doccount", psCount + "" + docCount);
                                                        if (taskcount == docCount) {
                                                            Log.e("entered inside", "equal loop");
                                                            while (count < 10 && count != ls_data.size()) {
                                                                Log.e("print cooouuu", String.valueOf(count));
                                                                loadList.add(ls_data.get(count));
                                                                System.out.println("Load List: " + loadList.get(count).getname());

                                                                count = count + 1;

                                                            }
                                                            mAdapter = new CustomAdaptersearch(searchps.this, loadList, searchps.this, flag, productid, String.valueOf(price), time);
                                                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                                            mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(loadList.size() - count, count);
                                                            mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener);
                                                            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }

//                                            try {
//                                                adapter = new CustomAdaptersearch(searchps.this, ls_data, searchps.this, flag,productid, price, time);
//                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
//                                                Log.e("Error", "Dashboard : " + ex);
//                                            }
//
//                                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                                            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener OnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {

            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (isLastItemDisplaying(recyclerView)) {

                int j = 0;

                while (j < 10 && count != ls_data.size()) {

                    loadList.add(ls_data.get(count));
                    count = count + 1;
                    j = j + 1;

                }

                //System.out.println("Count when load more: " + count2);

                mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(count - j, j);

                Log.i("ListActivity", "LoadMore");

            }

        }
    };

    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {

            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    // function for onbackpress

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            back();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        back();
    }
    void back(){
        Intent i = new Intent(searchps.this,personalshopperpage.class);
        i.putExtra("Flag", flag);
        if(productid != null) {
            i.putExtra("productId", productid);
            Log.e("get inback searchps",productid);
        }
        if(time!=null) {
            i.putExtra("time", time);
        }
        if(price!=null) {
            i.putExtra("price", price);
        }
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (registration!= null) {
            registration.remove();
            registration = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any version issue?

Comment: would you like to include your code?

Comment: tes @AtifPervaiz

Comment: can you pls check @AtifPervaiz

Comment: can someone pls ansewer

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your dependencies

implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"

Comment: will this work for all mobiles? is rest of my code good? @jack Huncho